# CORS header error when Angular use for front end and Laravel used for Backend

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

I am working with angular js 1.5 and laravel 5.4.

I have created middleware in laravel for CORS. It looks like below :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    if (!$request->isMethod('options')) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now, in Angular js I have created post request to get Bearer token so it work perfect. I got token in response. Then I have stored it into session and use interceptor to set token in header for all request.

My controller looks like :

```
app.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$http,$window,$state) {
$scope.vm.login = function() {

    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl+'auth/token',
            data: $.param($scope.vm.logDetails),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.access_token) {
                $window.sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo-token', response.data.access_token);
                $state.go('dashboard.masters_userroles');                   
            }               
        });
     }
});
```

My factory looks like below :

```
.factory('tokenInjector',function($window){
return {
    //For each request the interceptor will set the bearer token header.
    request: function($config) {

        if($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo-token'))
        {
            var token=$window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo-token');
            console.log(token);
            //set authorization header
            $config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
            $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;

        }
        return $config;
    }
}
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push('tokenInjector');
})
```

When it calls `$state.go('dashboard.masters_userroles');` this state then it gives an error like

`MLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.local.support.com/api/masters/userroles?page=1. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local.support.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use this package see if its resolve it:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

I use this package after fail making my own middleware too

Comment: thanks its work. But Do you know why my cors middleware is not working? And how to prevent GET method converted into OPTION in angular js when use GET request method